# HashMap with incorrect equals and HashCode implementation

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

According to what I have read,

> to use an object as the key to a hashMap, it has to provide a correct
>   override and implementation of the ***equals*** and ***hashCode***
>   method. HashMap get(Key k) method calls hashCode method on the key
>   object and applies returned ***hashValue*** to its own static hash
>   function to find a bucket location(backing array) where keys and
>   values are stored in form of a nested class called Entry (Map.Entry).
>   HashMap's internal hash Method defends against poor quality hash
>   functions.

To test these contracts, I have written a bean class with incorrect but legal implementations of the ***equals*** and ***hashCode*** method.

The class:

```
public class HashVO {

    private String studentName;
    private int age;
    private boolean isAdult;

    public HashVO(String studentName, int age, boolean isAdult) {
        super();
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.age = age;
        this.isAdult = isAdult;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public boolean isAdult() {
        return isAdult;
    }
    public void setAdult(boolean isAdult) {
        this.isAdult = isAdult;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return studentName + " : " + age + " : " + isAdult;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

}
```

In this case, the hash method of the HashMap,

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
        int h;
        return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
    }
```

should also return same value everytime because the hashcode always returns 31. So if objects of class HashVO are used as key of a hashMap, **the get method should not work, as it should go to the same bucket to retrieve the objects and the equals method always returns false so it will not be able to able to find a match for the key object**.

But when I am using this method,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<HashVO, String> voMap = new HashMap<HashVO, String>();
        HashVO vo = new HashVO("Item1", 25, true);
        HashVO vo1 = new HashVO("Item2", 12, false);
        HashVO vo2 = new HashVO("Item3", 1, false);
        voMap.put(vo, "Item");
        voMap.put(vo1, "Item1");
        voMap.put(vo2, "Item2");
        System.out.println(voMap.get(vo));
        System.out.println(voMap.get(vo1));
        System.out.println(voMap.get(vo2));
    }
```

the output is correct, and showing

```
Item
Item1
Item2
```

I want to understand why this correct output is coming even as the Equals and HashCode method implementation is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashMap` has a little trick where it compares object references before using `equals`. Since you're using the same object references for adding the elements and for retrieving them, `HashMap` will return them correctly.

See Java 7 source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.getEntry%28java.lang.Object%29) (Java 8 did a pretty big revamp of `HashMap` but it does something similar)

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        // HERE. Uses == with the key
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))) 
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that this isn't part of the docs, so don't depend on it.

Comment: I think you are right. I was using Java 8 to run the program. HashMap in Java 8 also has a similar implementation in the getNode method(line : 566).

Answer (score 1):

The HashMap works like this:

1) Index of table cell in which (Key,Value) will save calculates as key.hashCode();

2) Keys in HashMap compare by equals() or by reference comparing.

So, in your situation all pairs of (K,V) will store in one cell of HashMap table as LinkedList.
And you can get them from Map because references for keys will equals

Comment: Instead of key.equals(k), it should be k.equals(key). This way the keys in the map determine what they are mapped to instead of the key provided to get. For example, suppose I have a data structure that represents all strings of length 8. I define this as the class `FixedSizeStringOfLength8`. I define the `hashCode()` and `equals()` to be the same as String. However, the following will make `x` equal to null. 
`Map<FixedSizeStringOfLength8,String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(new FixedSizeStringOfLength8("12345678"), "Blah");

String x = map.get("12345678");`